# individual checkbox for each task returned in a ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I have a question about checkboxes. I am making a website that lets users enter their tasks for the day and can check the tasks off once they are complete. They can browse the tasks by selecting the date. I am using the AJAX get method to get the tasks from the database and display them in the webpage. I am not sure how to create a checkbox for each task I get from the AJAX method as I will be getting all the tasks for the selected date through one ajax call to the php script that connects to database and returns the tasks. And also how to identify which checkbox corresponds to which task.

In the db there are index numbers, task, date of the task, completed or not and the username

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is your _actual, specific question_. StackOverflow is not a good place to ask for general advice. Attempt something yourself, then come back with a _specific_ problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a JSON response from your PHP function that is returned with the ajax request and use the response to put the html in your page body.

For example, let's say you have the following PHP code:

```
 <?php

 $response = array(); 
$tasks = array(0 => "Task1", 1 => "Task1", 2 =>
 "Task1"); 

    $response['tasks'] = $tasks;


 $html = ''; 
 foreach($tasks AS $k => $v) {    
   $html .= '<input type="checkbox" id="task_' .$v. '" />'; 
 }

 $response['html'] = $html;

 echo json_encode($response); ?>
?>
```

And once your AJAX request finoshes, you can put the checkboxes in your page with jQuery(?)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
yourAjaxFunxtinHere().success(function()
{
   $('#container').html(response.html);
});
</script>
```